# SQL get number from right side of string without LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like, substr

I'm needing a solution to this query but I can't use a LIKE statement. I'm thinking I can use INSTR and SUBSTR but I'm not very well versed with those.

Ordinarily I could just do a LIKE '%7' But I can't do that here. The goal of this is to bring back a list of any row in my database that has a string in Column1  that ends in a 7. It's also noteworthy that not all of the strings are the same length, and that I am using Oracle SQL Developer. I've copied what the LIKE statement for this could look like below.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 LIKE '%7'
ORDER BY Column2;
```

Comment: But... why can't you use a like? What about `Regexp_like` or `Regexp_instr` are those allowed? Is this homework?

Comment: Can you give sample data and expected output you want to see?

Comment: With `Substr()` you could do `WHERE SUBSTR(Column1, -1) = 7` It's still an odd requirement though.

Comment: Why not use a `LIKE '%7'`? Is it because of performance issues for a `%` at the beginning of the pattern? Still quite odd requirement.

Comment: Sorry, but stating that you "can't" use a `LIKE` condition (it is a condition, not a statement), without explaining why, makes this a bad question in my book. -1 is for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```sql
SELECT x FROM t WHERE SUBSTR(x, -1) = '7'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, one simple solution is:

```
where regexp_like(x, '7$')
```

But it is unclear if you can use that function either.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the other solutions that I find simpler and good enough for most cases.

When using a pattern that starts with a `%` sometimes the query becomes [very] slow. If it's for performance issues, I would recommend an [overkill] solution that has a much better performance since it uses **Index Range Scan** rather than **Full Table Scan**:

1. Create a stored procedure to reverse the string:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ReverseOf(input IN varchar2) IS
       rev varchar2(50):='';
   BEGIN
       FOR i in reverse 1..length(input) LOOP
               rev := rev||substr(input, i, 1);
       END LOOP;
       dbms_output.put_line(rev);
   END;
   ```
2. Create a virtual column in the table:

   ```
   alter table table1 add column reversed_column1 
     generated always as (ReverseOf(column1)) virtual;
   ```
3. Create an index on the virtual column:

   ```
   create index ix_reverse_column1 on table1 (reversed_column1);
   ```
4. Use a "reverse LIKE" (that is very fast):

   ```
   SELECT Column1, Column2 
   FROM Table1
   WHERE reversed_column1 LIKE '7%' -- reverse pattern here!
   ORDER BY Column2;
   ```

Maybe overkill, but you may need it. It helped me a lot last year.

Comment: Way overkill. Why not simply create an index on `case when substr(column1, -1) = '7' then 1 end` (so, a function-based index)? Only non-null values are indexed, and those correspond to the needed rows. Or, for more generality, an index on `substr(column1, -1)`. Note that Oracle does **not** have a `reverseof()` function. It does have `reverse()`, which however is undocumented and unsupported - so it shouldn't be used in production environments.

Comment: @mathguy I know, I know... :D Anyway, for your solution you'll need to create one index per length of the pattern. If you need to search for two chars you need another index; for three chars a third one, etc. This solution creates a single fast index for ALL reverse searches.